# How to concat a tensor in pytorch?

Tags: list, pytorch, tensor

What I want to do is something like this:

```
import torch 
a = torch.arange(120).reshape(2, 3, 4, 5)
b = torch.cat(list(a), dim=2)
```

I want to know:

1. I have to convert tensor to a list, will this cause performance not good?
2. Even performance is OK, can I do this just with tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to:

1. Reduce the number of copies: in this specific scenario, copies need to be made since we are rearranging the layout of our underlying data.
2. Reduce or remove any `torch.Tensor` -> non-`torch.Tensor` conversions: this will be a pain point when working with a GPU since you're transferring data in and out of the device.

You can perform the same operation by permuting the axes such that `axis=0` goes to `axis=-2` (the before the last axis), then flattening the last two axes:

```
>>> a.permute(1,2,0,3).flatten(-2)
tensor([[[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64],
         [  5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69],
         [ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74],
         [ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79]],

        [[ 20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84],
         [ 25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89],
         [ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94],
         [ 35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99]],

        [[ 40,  41,  42,  43,  44, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104],
         [ 45,  46,  47,  48,  49, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
         [ 50,  51,  52,  53,  54, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114],
         [ 55,  56,  57,  58,  59, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]]])
```